# My sql get id which has maximum likes grouped by column and ordered by sum(likes)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve data from a view. View will have details such as country, location_id, content_id, content_url, content_likes and .... I need to retrieve location_id which has max(content_likes) grouped by country order by sum(content_likes) desc.

Right now I am getting the correct data based on country side, but Id I am getting which is of default order. But instead of default ordered id I need to get Id which has maximum likes.

My current query is

```
select * from <view_name> group by country order by sum(content_likes) desc;
```

Data From View:

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: `select *` with `group by` shows a lack of understanding of how SQL works.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue resolved with below sql

```
select t.location_id,t.content_likes from 
(select country,max(content_likes) as mcl,sum(content_likes) as scl from test_eresh
group by country) x,
test_eresh t
where t.country = x.country
and t.content_likes = x.mcl
order by x.scl desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like:

```
select country_id, location_id, sum(content_likes)
from view_name vn
group by country_id, location_id
having location_id = (select vn2.location_id
                      from view_name vn
                      where vn2.country_id = vn.country_id
                      group by location_id
                      order by sum(content_likes) desc
                      limit 1
                     );
```

Comment: I applied this query but I am getting same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (sorry any syntax error):

```
    select cc.*
      from     
        (select aa.location_id, aa.country /*[, add fields if you need them...]*/,
               rank() over (partition by aa.country_id order by aa.content_likes) ranking_field
          from <view_name> aa
          join (select country, sum(content_likes) sum_content_likes
                  from <view_name>
                 group by country) bb
            on aa.country=bb.country) cc
    where ranking_field=1
order by cc.sum_content_likes desc
```

This returns only the location with max likes in each country ordered by the total likes in each country

EDIT:

With your new example, perhaps you can do simply this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <<view>> aa
  JOIN(SELECT country, MAX(content_likes) max_likes
         FROM <<view>>
        GROUP BY country) bb
    ON aa.country=bb.country
   AND aa.content_likes=bb.max_likes
```

It is two pass query but give your example result. It can return more than one row for country if more than one location has same likes number and those are the max likes in that country.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response I am using mysql server. rank() is not supported in mysql server. Can you provide any other pointers?

Comment: Im not expert in mysql... perhaps you can use this workarround: http://kennethxu.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/analytical-function-in-mysql-rownumber.html

Comment: Please, review edited answer with your latest example.